# Background behind my text goes to the very end of the page instead of stopping

Tags: html, css

Well I want to add kind of a transparent, blurred out background behind my text so the image that my text is on still can be visible. Kind of like this....

[image]

But my problem is that even though the transparent background appears as planned, it goes on "forever" to the right until it hits the edge of the page, instead of stopping where the text ends. Any thoughts how I can fix that?

**CSS**

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    top: 300px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `width: 100%;` in your styles. Remove it and make it `width: auto;`. And that's CSS not HTML!

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    color: white;
    width: auto; /* Epic Miss */
    top: 300px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: inline;
}
```

Also giving `display: inline` would help.

Comment: Haha, the amount of time it took to write the question vs. actually reading your own 8 lines of CSS :D

Comment: @Shomz, Why? Which is long?

Comment: I meant for OP - took a great deal to nicely format the question, yet didn't bother reading his own few lines of code. :) I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Er... He he... I still don't understand. I formatted the OP's question as well as answered so quickly. Did you mean that? `:P` Sorry I guess I am a bit dumb right now! `:(` End of the Day!